# How to run long running tasks and return result immediately?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I would like to run the tasks and return the result immediately

```
tasks = [
   asyncio.create_task(self.start_update(update, spec))
   for update, spec in zip(updates, specs)
]

return Report(updates=updates,job_task=asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```

Now I want to change the logic and send a slack msg after my tasks will be completed, so I changed the code:

```
tasks = [
    asyncio.create_task(self._start_update(update, spec))
    for update, spec in zip(updates, specs)
]

task = asyncio.create_task(self.notify_as_completed(tasks))
return Report(updates=updates,job_task=asyncio.gather(task))

--------------------------------
async def notify_as_completed(self, tasks) -> None:
    try:
        execute_response = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await self._slack_service.send_msg(execute_response)
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error(f"wasn't able to send a slack msg: {ex}")
```

Is it a good pattern or there is a better way?

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews.

Comment: You don't need to `gather()` a single task, `job_task=task` will do just as well.